# AAD Graph User Patch authorization issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting an unauthorized error when trying to `PATCH` a User entity with AAD Graph (in a B2C tenant). The token, acquired using Client Creds flow with symmetric key has `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission for `graph.windows.net` resource. What am I missing? (Must the token be acquired using X509 perhaps?)

```
Response:
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}


Request
https://graph.windows.net/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/users/c064a6a5-...1f5a0?api-version=1.6
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 241
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IndVTG1ZZnNxZFF1V3RWXy1oeFZ0REpKWk00USIsImtpZCI6IndVTG1ZZnNxZFF1V3RWXy1oeFZ0REpKWk00USJ9.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.ZAARkTCSK1MYDj3TnDY8djUxienvmNySn0sNR1iZ4eDdYLSrtqjVG2E9EL4nlSYIIP92HZ6io3MdASxsfHrbZaSTvgy6gqe2dNJZ_aWh23TyHop3q5ctLCTqQpNEP1AGcq6vnXk2ceN5CMXkzK1d8R3Zlwa3ICo7lWFDKDEea0_Y87Hvm8U2-zjgzhqAiZi6sH3u7BxiZBqWop4Jn9Wddv2qq_lGU7UuzEwbTMFQ87BKWvts3K_H4UnzZDvDrwSi_GrwvG9VBQ1ST66qhGLRESnW0u_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting an unauthorized error when trying to PATCH a User entity with AAD Graph

I suppose you are using the aad graph to [reset a user's password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).

As the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#directoryreadwriteall-privileges-detail) mentioned, for `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, No rights to reset user passwords.

[image]

If you want to reset the password, it also has been mentioned in the doc, you should use `delegated` scope `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission.

> **Important**
>
> Either `delegated` scope `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is required to reset a user's password. In addition to the correct scope, the signed-in user would need sufficient privileges to reset another user's password.